# getLastSignedInAccount NULL exception

Tags: android, google-api, wear-os, google-fit

I am trying to add support for the Google Fit API to my smartwatch app. Every time I test on the smartwatch it shows me the accounts to choose from. After I click on the account, it's throwing a null reference exception from `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount`. I checked with my OAuth2, I have it and it seems fine. I am totally confused what is going on now.

Here is the code of my activity:

```
public class Feedback extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private GoogleApiClient mClient;
    public static final String TAG = "StepCounter";
    private int todaystep;
    private static final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMI = 012;
    private static final int FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE = 0302;
    GoogleSignInOptionsExtension fitnessOptions;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleSignInAccount gsa;
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient;
    private String ClientID ="118180900116-e1t1gr7q4ud2dvceg7ocudppv5rk039b.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback_swip);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
        }
         mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                 .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                 .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
                 .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                 .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                 .useDefaultAccount()
                 .build();

        fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();

           gsa = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);// I debug here and it shows that the gsa is NULL

           gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
                   .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                   .requestServerAuthCode(ClientID)
                   .requestEmail()
                   .addExtension(fitnessOptions)
                   .build();

        if (!hasOAuthPermission()) {
            requestOAuthPermission();
        }
        subscribe();
        accessGoogleFit();

        System.out.print("this is the today steps " + todaystep);
    }

    private boolean hasOAuthPermission() {
        return GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions);
    }

    private void requestOAuthPermission() {
        Scope scopeLocation = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE);
        Scope scopesActivity = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE);
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMI,       
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                scopeLocation);
    }

    private void accessGoogleFit() {
        // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
        Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
        Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

        //signInClient =GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        Task<DataReadResponse> response = Fitness.getHistoryClient(this,  gsa).readData(readRequest);// Here will also give the NUll since gsa is null
        List<DataSet> weekdataSets = response.getResult().getDataSets();
        System.out.print(" this is waht is should be " + weekdataSets.get(0).getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt());
        for (int i = 0; i < weekdataSets.size(); i++) {
            if (weekdataSets != null) {
                this.weekstep[i] = weekdataSets.get(i).getDataPoints().get(i).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                this.weekheartrate[i] = weekdataSets.get(i).getDataPoints().get(i).getValue(Field.FIELD_BPM).asInt();
                System.out.print("weekdataSets.size"+weekdataSets.size());
                FeedbackContentTextView.setText(weekdataSets.size());
            }
        }
        // Setting a start and read the total steps from 00:00 till now
        int total = 0;
        PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
            total = totalSet.isEmpty()
                    ? 0
                    : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.");
        }
        todaystep = total;
        Log.i(TAG, "Total steps: " + total);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if( !authInProgress ) {
            try {
                authInProgress = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult( Feedback.this, REQUEST_OAUTH );
            } catch(IntentSender.SendIntentException e ) {

            }
        } else {
            Log.e( "GoogleFit", "authInProgress" );
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE )
                .setDataSourceTypes( DataSource.TYPE_RAW )
                .build();

        ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                for( DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources() ) {
                    if( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals( dataSource.getDataType() ) ) {
                        registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, dataSourceRequest)
                .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
        } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode ==REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress=false;
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            subscribe();
            if (requestCode == GOOGLE_FIT_PERMI) {
                if(!mClient.isConnecting()&&!mClient.isConnected())
                    mClient.connect();
            } else if(requestCode==RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("GoogleFit", "Result Cancelled");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Records step data by requesting a subscription to background step data.
     */
    public void subscribe() {
        // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
        // active, fitness data will start recording.

        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, gsa)
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                });
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, gsa)
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                });
        FeedbackContentTextView.setText("We cant find your account");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use

```
GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
```

instead of

```
GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
```

Comment: thanks very much. Now it does not throw the Null exceptions anymore. However, when it runs and I click the account for the app, it leads to a blank screen of nothing. Meanwhile, List<DataSet> weekdataSets = response.getResult().getDataSets(); gives another exception of "IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete". Did I miss something?